# How to list instance methods of an object class without listing the methods of the superclasses

Tags: ruby

The method `methods` returns a list of all methods of a class, for example if I call `'miguel'.methods`, I will get a list of all the methods in the class `String`.

I would like to list the methods of a class, excluding the methods of its superclasses. For example, a list of instance methods that are defined on `String`, including modules included into `String`.

I also would like to know how to list instance methods that are exclusively defined on the object class without listing instance methods included in modules included by the class.

Comment: @AshikSalman almost, but in this question the receiver is an instance (e.g. `'miguel'`), in the other question it is the class itself (e.g. `String`).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what *precisely* is unclear to you about the documentation of `Object#methods`, so that the Ruby developers can improve the documentation for future users.

Comment: @JörgWMittag perhaps is because the name of the method `:methods` but I could not found where it was defined. Thanks for pointing at it, I should have guess that is was in `Object`

Comment: If you want to know where a method is defined, you can just ask it: `''.method(:methods).owner`. There is also a search function on the Ruby-Doc.Org site that lets you search for methods. (This is handy, because in YARV, from which the docs are generated, some methods are actually defined on `Kernel` but documented on `Object`, which can be confusing.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class.instance_methods(false)
```

Here for string as example:

```
'miguel'.class.instance_methods(false)
```

Comment: will this include the methods defined by modules included into the class `String`?

Comment: @MiguelSalas no, it does not (just give it a try). On the other hand, it doesn't include singleton methods, either.

Comment: Beware of `'miguel'.extend(Module.new { def foo; :bar; end }).class.instance_methods(false).detect { |m| m == :foo } #⇒ nil`. That said, methods that are defined on the instance itself won’t be returned by this call.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes, that is what @Stefan  meant with `singleton methods`  methods that belong to a singleton class. By the way people call that  'anonymous classes' by many names singleton class, eigenclass, ghost class (Dave Thomas) and anonymous class are all synonymous in this context.